# How to use v-for with lits specified inline?

Tags: vue.js, v-for

This is the normal way it is presented

```
  <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.message">
    {{ item.message }}
  </li>
```

But I want something like this

```
  <li v-for="item in ['a', 'b', 'c']" :key="item.message">
    {{ item.message }}
  </li>
```

Comment: please clarify more

Comment: This v-for works in my experience, but 'a'.message doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objects you are iterating has no `message` key. This should work:

```js
<li v-for="item in [{message: 'foo'}, {message: 'bar'}]" :key="item.message">
    {{ item.message }}
</li>
```

or

```js
<li v-for="item in ['a', 'b', 'c']" :key="item">
    {{ item }}
</li>
```